# I want to connect by specifying the IP address with M2MQTT

Tags: c#, mqtt, mosquitto

I made mosquitto in docker a broker.

Suppose my PC IP address is "10.0.0.11".

I wrote code like this.

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient ("10.0.0.11", 1883, false, null, null, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);
```

However, when the Connect method was executed, "isConnect" was false.

```
client.Connect (clientId);
```

If you specify the host name of HIVE MQ, it works.([HIVE MQ](http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/))

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient ("broker.mqttdashboard.com");
```

Please tell me how to enable connection by specifying IP address.

Comment: Edit the question to show what error message you get when it doesn't work

Comment: Also does the TLS certificate for your machine include the IP address as the CN or as a SAN entry?

Comment: Setting the user ID and password when connecting worked wellclient.Connect(clientId, user id, password);

Comment: Can you ping broker IP address?

Answer (score 0):

The IP address must be appropriate.
(Even though a warning about deprecation pops up in the IDE, this type of IP address conversion has worked for me.)

```
System.Net.IPAddress broker = 
System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.11");

client = new MqttClient(broker, 1883, false, null, null, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);
```